# How to stop using a method temporarily in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Every time I touch a node to move, a method is triggered, so I want to stop that method only when the touchesMoved method is in use in SpriteKit, swift. I tried writing like addBlocks() == nil inside the touchesMoved, but useless. How am I able to stop that method to be called when I touch a node?  After finishing moving that node, I want it to be in use again. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addBlocks() == nil // this returns false
```

I suggest that you override `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and trigger a boolean to stop addBlocks being called. Or just call `addBlocks()` inside the `touchesBegan` event.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, it worked!! This is what I needed! Thanks so much!